# Freq table with percentages using multiple columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, frequency

Please help - I am trying to produce a freq table with row percentages using multiple columns. I know this is simple but I can't seen to find a straightforward code online. Please see example below, where 0 is no and 1 is yes.

```
df <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"), fci_1 = c("1","0","0","0","1","0"), fci_2 = c("1","0","1","1",NA,"0"), fci_3 = c("1","1","1","1",NA,"0"),fci_4 = c("1","0","1","1","1","1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -6L))
```

Desired table:

| FCI | NO (%) | Yes (%) | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fci_1 | 4 (66) | 2 (34) | 0 |
| fci_2 | 2 (33) | 3 (50) | 1 (17) |
| fci_3 | 1 (17) | 4 (66) | 1 (17) |
| fci_4 | 1 (17) | 5 (83) | 0 |

What I've tried

```
library (table1)

df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor)

table1(~ fci_1 + fci_2 + fci_3 + fci_4 | subject_id, data=df)
```

Which is very similar to what I want but not quite. This shows table per subject_id. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-subject_id, names_to = "FCI") |> 
  group_by(FCI) |> 
  summarise(n = n(),
            No = sum(value == 0), 
            Yes = sum(value == 1), 
            "NA" = sum(value == "NA")) |> 
  mutate(across(c(No, Yes, `NA`), ~ paste0(.x, " (", round(100 * .x / n), ")"))) |> 
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, " (%)"), c(No, Yes, `NA`)) |> 
  select(-n)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   FCI   `No (%)` `Yes (%)` `NA (%)`
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
#> 1 fci_1 4 (67)   2 (33)    0 (0)   
#> 2 fci_2 2 (33)   3 (50)    1 (17)  
#> 3 fci_3 1 (17)   4 (67)    1 (17)  
#> 4 fci_4 1 (17)   5 (83)    0 (0)
```

**EDIT** For the new data which has true `NA`s you could do:

```r
df <- structure(list(
  subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"),
  fci_1 = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), fci_2 = c("1", "0", "1", "1", NA, "0"), 
  fci_3 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", NA, "0"), fci_4 = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1")
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-subject_id, names_to = "FCI") |>
  group_by(FCI) |>
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    No = sum(value %in% 0),
    Yes = sum(value %in% 1),
    "NA" = sum(is.na(value))
  ) |>
  mutate(across(c(No, Yes, `NA`), ~ paste0(.x, " (", round(100 * .x / n), ")"))) |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, " (%)"), c(No, Yes, `NA`)) |>
  select(-n)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   FCI   `No (%)` `Yes (%)` `NA (%)`
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
#> 1 fci_1 4 (67)   2 (33)    0 (0)   
#> 2 fci_2 2 (33)   3 (50)    1 (17)  
#> 3 fci_3 1 (17)   4 (67)    1 (17)  
#> 4 fci_4 1 (17)   5 (83)    0 (0)
```

Comment: I realised that the dataset I provided was treating NA as a character/factor and not necessarily actual NA. This code only works when the NAs are removed, however, I need to show the NAs. I've tried ```df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-subject_id, names_to = "FCI") |> 
  group_by(FCI) |> 
  summarise(n = n(),
            No = sum(value == 0,na.rm = TRUE), 
            Yes = sum(value == 1,na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  mutate(across(c(No, Yes, `NA`), ~ paste0(.x, " (", round(100 * .x / n), ")"))) |> 
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, " (%)"), c(No, Yes, `NA`)) |> 
  select(-n)```

Comment: This works on normal R script but produces and error when used in R markdown ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "call_text", value = c("dplyr::select(...)",  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 3
Calls: <Anonymous> ... trace_format_branch -> trace_as_tree -> $<- -> $<-.data.frame```. Do you know another way I can do this or possibly help with why I am getting the error?

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`

```
tbl1 <- table(stack(df[-1])[2:1])
tbl1[] <- sprintf('%d (%d)', tbl1, round(100 *proportions(tbl1, 1)))
colnames(tbl1) <- c("No (%)", "Yes (%)", "NA (%)")
```

-output

```
> tbl1
       values
ind     No (%) Yes (%) NA (%)
  fci_1 4 (67) 2 (33)  0 (0) 
  fci_2 2 (33) 3 (50)  1 (17)
  fci_3 1 (17) 4 (67)  1 (17)
  fci_4 1 (17) 5 (83)  0 (0)
```